# Extra node hanging around on list - using recursion to generate lists with a given length

Tags: java, list, recursion, methods, nodes

I am given an array of 4 `chars`, `['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']`, and have to recursively generate lists with a given length and GC content (the amount of G's and C's in a  list). I'm able to recursively generate the lists and check if they met the conditions, however after the first iteration of the for loop (see below), the 'A' that is the first node of the list for the first iteration sticks around.

The three other methods in this project are: `gcContent` (returns an int that represents the GC content of a list), `reverseComplement` (returns the reverse complement of a list, ie in reverse order and all the chars are switched to their complement; A<>G, C<>T), and `compare` (which compares two lists and returns true if they are the same).

Here is what I currently have for `reverseComplement`:

```
public void generateStrands(int n, int k, int rate, Node t){
    cont = 0;
    char[] array = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
    if(k == n){
        if(!compare(t, reverseComplement(t)) && gcContent(t) == rate){
            t.printListLn();
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            t.add(array[i]);
            generateStrands(n, k+1, rate, t);
            t.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my `add` and `remove` methods for my `Node` class:

```
public void add(char c){

        if(base == ' '){
            base = c;
        }
        else{
            Node p = this;
            Node q = null;
            while(p!=null){
              q = p;
              p = p.next;
            }
            q.next = new Node(c, null);
        }
    }

    public void remove(){

        if(base == ' ' || next == null){
            return;
        }
        else{
            Node p = this;
            Node q = null;
            while(p.next!=null){
                q = p;
                p = p.next;
            }
            q.next = null;
        }
    }
```

And here is the output I get (n = 2, rate = 1):

```
AC
AG
ACA
ACT
AGA
AGT
ATC
ATG
```

I've tried playing around with the `remove` method, but I'm fairly sure that that method is not the issue and that it may be the order of certain lines of code in the `generateStrands` method.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed three cases for `remove`: one if the list is empty, one if there is only one element, and lastly if there are 2 or more elements.

```
public void remove(){
    if(base == ' ')
        return;
    else if(next == null)
        base = ' ';
    else{
        Node p = this;
        Node q = null;
        while(p.next!=null){
            q = p;
            p = p.next;
        }
        q.next = null;
    }
}
```

With this version of `remove`, the program works flawlessly.